# Python 3 Simple Xor Pipe/CLI Program

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, console

I wrote a simple Python 3 program that takes data from either a file or standard input and xor encrypts or decrypts the data. By default, the output is encoded in base64, however there is a flag for disabling that `--raw`. It works as intended except when I am using the raw mode, in which case an extra line and some random data is appended to the output when decrypting xor data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import cycle
import argparse
import base64

import re
def xor(data, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(str(a)) ^ ord(str(b))) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))

# check if a string is base64 encoded.
def is_base64(s):
    pattern = re.compile("^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$")
    if not s or len(s) < 1:
        return False
    else:
        return pattern.match(s)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-', dest='data', help='Data to encrypt'
                                                                                                      'or decrypt')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--raw', dest='raw', default=False, action='store_true', help='Do not use base64 encoding')
    parser.add_argument('-k', '--key', dest='key', help='Key to encrypt with', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    data = args.data.read()
    key = args.key
    raw = args.raw
    if raw:
        ret = xor(data, key)
        print(str(ret))
    else:
        if is_base64(data):
            # print('is base64')
            decoded = base64.b64decode(data).decode()
            ret = xor(decoded, key)
            print(ret)
        else:
            # print('is not base64')
            ret = xor(data, key)
            encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(ret, "utf-8"))
            print(encoded.decode())
```

When running without the `--raw` flag, everything performs as intended:

```
$ echo lol|./xor.py -k 123  
XV1fOw==
echo lol|./xor.py -k 123 |./xor.py -k 123
lol
```

However, if I disable base64, something rather odd happens. It's easier to demonstrate then it is to explain:

```
$ echo lol|./xor.py -k 123 -r |./xor.py -k 123 -r
lol
8
```

Does anyone know why I am seeing the character `8` appended to the output of xor decrypted data? I have a c program called [xorpipe](https://gist.github.com/darkerego/f7880ee8878b64a9f6ce945d7cf98aa4) that I use for this exact use case, and it does not suffer this bug. I wanted to rewrite it in Python.

I am looking for other constructive criticism, suggestions, or reviews as well.  Particular, I would like argparse to be able to determine whether the supplied input is either a file, string, or data piped from standard input. This is easy to accomplish bash or C, but I am not sure how best to do this in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why I am seeing the character 8 appended to the output of xor decrypted data?

The statement `echo lol` pipes `lol\n\r` to Python, which encodes the line breaks as `;_` which is decoded into an `8`. Unfortunately `echo -n` doesn't work here but adding `.strip()` to the input data in the Python script fixes this issue.

PEP8 is Python's internal coding standards which specify how line breaks and code should be structured: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ . The guide is very long; you can use `autopep8` to auto-format the code.

```
    if raw:
        ret = xor(data, key)
        print(str(ret))
    else:
        if is_base64(data):
            # print('is base64')
            decoded = base64.b64decode(data).decode()
            ret = xor(decoded, key)
            print(ret)
        else:
            # print('is not base64')
            ret = xor(data, key)
            encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(ret, "utf-8"))
            print(encoded.decode())
```

I would simplify the nested if-statements and add a `return` to `print(str(ret))` then the `is_base64` could be unindented, or I would set a variable called `decoded` to the final string to print, then print it out at the end of the `if/elif` loop.

`is_base64(s)` could just run `base64.b64decode(data).decode()` and return `False` if any exceptions were thrown during decoding instead of the regex.

I would remove the commented out code such as `# print('is base64')`.

Comment: Ah, that is really obvious now that you have pointed it out. </facepalm> Thanks, that solves the issue!

Comment: The reason why I am using a regex to check whether or not the data is base64 or not is because I was having issues with the method of decoding and then re-encoding the input, and the regex seemed to work better, so out of all the solutions I found in this thread that method seemed to work best for this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315398/check-if-a-string-is-encoded-in-base64-using-python - i don't remember exactly what the issue was, I will double check that though. Thank you very much.